# Erro Conectar Android Json Parse HTTP Mostrando no Fragment

Tags: android

Estou com um problema na hora de conectar, alguém poderia me ajudar por favor. Sou novato e não estou conseguindo fazer a conexão do JSON PARSE HTTP com o FRAGMENTS todos os tutoriais mostram com ACTIVITY, mas já tentei converter e não consigo, sou grato, caso possam me ajudar.

Código JSONParser.java

```
package br.com.menuruenf.menuruenf.domain;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

/**
 * Created by Rodolfo on 15/09/2015.
 */
 public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

 // constructor
public JSONParser() {

    }

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
        }

        is.close();

        json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
      jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

Código DinnerFragment.java

```
package br.com.menuruenf.menuruenf.fragments;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;

import br.com.menuruenf.menuruenf.R;
import br.com.menuruenf.menuruenf.domain.Dinner;
import br.com.menuruenf.menuruenf.domain.JSONParser;

/**
 * Created by Rodolfo on 01/09/2015.
 */
public class DinnerFragment extends BaseFragment  {


//URL to get JSON Array
 private static String url = "http://menu-api.herokuapp.com/dinners.json";

//JSON Node data
private static final String TAG_DINNER              = "";
private static final String TAG_ID                  = "id";
private static final String TAG_DATE                = "date";
private static final String TAG_SALAD               = "salad";
private static final String TAG_ACCOMPANIMENT       = "accompaniment";
private static final String TAG_GARNISH             = "garnish";
private static final String TAG_PROTEIN1            = "protein1";
private static final String TAG_PROTEIN2            = "protein2";
private static final String TAG_PROTEIN3            = "protein3";
private static final String TAG_DESSERT             = "dessert";
private static final String TAG_JUICE               = "juice";

JSONArray dinner = null;

TextView dinner_id;
TextView dinner_date;
TextView dinner_salad;
TextView dinner_accompaniment1;
TextView dinner_garnish;
TextView dinner_protein1;
TextView dinner_protein2;
TextView dinner_protein3;
TextView dinner_dessert;
TextView dinner_juice;





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){




    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dinner, container, false);


    //Import TextView
    dinner_date             = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_date);
    dinner_salad            = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_salad);
    dinner_accompaniment1   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_accompaniment1);
    dinner_garnish          = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_garnish);
    dinner_protein1         = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_protein1);
    dinner_protein2         = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_protein2);
    dinner_protein3         = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_protein3);
    dinner_dessert          = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_dessert);
    dinner_juice            = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinner_juice);

    //Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);



    try {

        //Getting JSON Array
        dinner          = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DINNER);
        JSONObject c    = dinner.getJSONObject(0);


        //Storing JSON item in a Variable
        String did               = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String ddate             = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
        String dsalad            = c.getString(TAG_SALAD);
        String daccompaniment    = c.getString(TAG_ACCOMPANIMENT);
        String dgarnish          = c.getString(TAG_GARNISH);
        String dprotein1         = c.getString(TAG_PROTEIN1);
        String dprotein2         = c.getString(TAG_PROTEIN2);
        String dprotein3         = c.getString(TAG_PROTEIN3);
        String ddessert          = c.getString(TAG_DESSERT);
        String djuice            = c.getString(TAG_JUICE);


        //Set JSON DATA in TextView
        dinner_date.setText(ddate);
        dinner_salad.setText(dsalad);
        dinner_accompaniment1.setText(daccompaniment);
        dinner_garnish.setText(dgarnish);
        dinner_protein1.setText(dprotein1);
        dinner_protein2.setText(dprotein2);
        dinner_protein3.setText(dprotein3);
        dinner_dessert.setText(ddessert);
        dinner_juice.setText(djuice);



    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return view;
    }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

UPDATE
Uma Ótima solução é o retrofit, simples e funcional.

Comment: Rodolfo, esse é um problema muito comum no desenvolvimento Android e requer uma boa mudança na forma como está desenvolvendo. Indo direto ao ponto, não se pode fazer requisições de rede ou acessos a disco (em geral operações bloqueantes) na `MainThread`. Recomendo dar uma olhada no conceito de Threading. O mais simples seria usar uma `AsyncTask` que é uma camada de abstração sobre uma Thread. Mas além disso, recomendo ver os efeitos de se usar `AsyncTasks`. Aqui no StackOverflow tem diversas perguntas sobre `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Boa tarde, então implementei com o AsyncTasks só que  uso fragment e não activiy e to com muito problema na hora de transformar activity para fragment exemplo activityAtual.this

Comment: Uma forma fácil de acessar o contexto do seu `Fragment` eu recomendo o `getContext` se estiver usando a `Support Library v4` ou então `getActivity` caso contrário.

Comment: Utilizeii o retrofit melhorou a minha vida.